# Control a trigger in SQL

Tags: sql-server, batch-file

I would like to know how we can control a trigger in SQL when the process is in progress.
Example: If any Update, Delete, Insert operation performed on a table (Employee Table) then I am executing a batch file located in the windows drive. Here the batch file takes around 5 minutes to complete the whole process. So my question here is for suppose I have a multiple application connected to the same table (Employee Table) and if different an performed on the table from Application and due to trigger the batch process started. In meanwhile from another application one more operation performed then it triggers  the batch file again. Due to which the performance is degrading or getting crashed.

So here i would like to know is there any way to control the trigger. Such as until the batch file completes the process the second trigger is kept on hold and after the completion the process needs to be started again.

Comment: what does the batch file do ?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a helper table where your sp check if running = 0, if so, writes 1 and batch starts. When the batch ends, set running = 0.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh - Having a database trigger execute a batch script on the server sounds like a horrible idea. And it takes 5 minutes!!!???? You've pretty much abandoned the idea of concurrency, and it does not sound like a very stable system.

But assuming you really want to move forward with this design. I suggest that ***any*** process that performs DML on the table should establish an exclusive lock on the table *before* the DML is executed. Your trigger(s) are always executed *after* the DML is complete on SQL Server, which I suspect is too late.

I recommend that you force all DML on that table to be through stored procedures that always establish the table lock before proceeding. Your actions are thus guaranteed to be serialized, your batch script never executes more than once at any given time, and concurrent requests will be queued.

You could restrict write access to the table by giving write access to a single account that owns the stored procedures, and then grant execute privilege on the procedures to appropriate users/roles.

***Actually, I recommend that you abandon your design completely. But I can't suggest an alternative because I have no idea what led you to your current design***